# Quick and Easy Data Model Diagrams (ERD)

Tags: database, data-visualization, er-diagram

When I'm doing documentation, I frequently want to build a small ERD by hand to demonstrate a couple of relationships that are associated with the current topic.

I *can* do it in Visio, and frequently do, but it's a pain in the neck sometimes.  Visio has rules in place that are sometimes difficult to configure and sometimes the line endings are painful to change.  The plus side to using Visio as opposed to anything else that allows you to quickly draw boxes is that the line endings can be used to easily interpret the relationship (one to many, many to many, zero or one, etc.).

I'm not looking for a full blown modeling tool that can generate SQL, more just a quick and easy diagram tool with appropriate ERD connectors.

Here's a sample image so you know what I'm talking about:

[image]

I can use a Windows, Linux or web based tool.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ERD, but I've used drawing applications for other kinds of diagrams. How sensitive are ERD diagrams to precise placement? How diverse are the “arrow” symbols? Is there a lot of duplication, e.g. do you tend to have many similar diagrams or parts? Do you want to generate the diagram from source code or a WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: I know that this question is rather old, but if you specify which database you are suing, then maybe we can help you even further (specially if it's MySql ;-)

Comment: @Mawg - I'm pretty set with GraphViz at this point, but I always appreciate looking at new things.  I use postgres and oracle mostly these days when I'm using a relational database.

Comment: No ERD, but for Oracle, http://www.sqltools.net/ is useful (and free)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest looking at:

1. [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) it is free, runs on Windows, Linux & Mac.  You
   describe what you need and it draws it for you - i.e. You define the
   nodes and connections with overrides on colours, line types, etc.  - There is a bit of a 
   learning curve but the results are very good so it is worth persevering.
   and you can generate your output in a wide range of formats.

   **Pros:** Once you are familiar with it it is very fast, allows you to generate your 
   diagrams for almost any output format and does the layout automatically for you.  There
   are a large number of tools that make use of it to generate diagrams automatically 
   such as doxygen.  Available for most platforms.

   **Cons:** There is a fairly steep learning curve.
2. [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/yed) this has a graphical user interface and is available for most platforms.

   **Pros:** There is a GUI so easy to use, Java so available for a lot of platforms.

   **Cons:** Large, Java so slow.

Comment: Could you please describe WHY you are suggesting those ? What are the goods and bads in each one?

Comment: I took a look at both yesterday.  Both are quick installs and free.  yEd is easy, but not quite as easy as I hoped.  GraphViz will be as easy as I hoped once I figure out how to define a dot file.  SchemaSpy shows a good output example, but I haven't delved into the source enough to figure out how. http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/relationships.html

Answer (score 5):

I think [QuickDatabaseDiagrams](http://www.QuickDatabaseDiagrams.com) will suit you perfectly... but I do work there!

[image: Quick Database Diagrams animation]

**Pros**

- Free
- It really is very quick. You just type and it draws the diagram.
- Relationships are drawn from field to field so it's clear what's going on.
- Web based so easy to access and share diagrams.

**Cons**

For your use case I honestly can't think of any. Other users should note that you can't define indexes or defaults, but it's on the roadmap.

Comment: Could be what I was looking for.  (cf websequencediagrams.com ; PlantUML;  Mermaid, was it?)
I'm looking for a way to turn off the datatypes though.  Otherwise, I can't show people my "quick" database diagrams until I've got all the datatypes straight or else I'm misleading them....

Comment: Ah, to have no datatypes shown on the diagram at all you need to (not specify them and) _remove_ the DefaultFieldType setting.  
(Now I can't find any settings for colo(u)rs, font-faces or sizes... :-) )

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll consider removing the DefaultFieldType setting from the default diagram as I can image how that could be confusing. Formatting is in the feature backlog. You can vote for it our on our [roadmap on Trello](https://trello.com/c/tPH2zN3b/36-custom-formatting)!

Answer (score 3):

[ERWin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_ERwin_Data_Modeler) is one of the good ones that I used. Not sure if it qualifies as "easy" for you, but it was for me. Sample diagram picture [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/73/ERWin_4.1.4.3643_on_Windows_2000_screenshot.png/730px-ERWin_4.1.4.3643_on_Windows_2000_screenshot.png) (too big to inline).

If you use AquaDataStudio, it includes ERD tool. Inferior to ERWin in my opinion, but that's subjective, functionality wise both are OK for what you need. Frankly I'm not very happy with line placement rules in it.

Embarkadero ER studio was recommended to me by people I asked but I never used it.

More competing tools I haven't used can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#ER_diagramming_tools

Comment: $4,794.00 for ERWin Standard, holy cow!  Then I saw the free community edition.  Whew!  Thanks for the minor heart attack :)

Comment: You can download the free community edition from  http://erwin.com/products/data-modeler/community-edition/  BUT, note that "The CA ERwin Data Modeler Community Edition offers many of the core features of data modeling with a limit of 25 model objects. - See more at: http://erwin.com/products/data-modeler/community-edition/#sthash.848i9u4a.dpuf"  Btw, it is Windows only and supports  Oracle
SQL Server
DB2 UDB
MySQL
ODBC
Sybase

Comment: it seems ERWin Community Edition doesn't exist any more :(

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite an ERD diagram designer but depending on your needs it might work well.

[yUML](http://yuml.me/diagram/nofunky/class/draw)

It lets you draw Class, Activity, & Use Case Diagrams via simple text input (it draws the diagram for you)

With options to save as a PNG image, SVG, etc.

e.g. Here's a quickly hacked up image...
[image]

Comment: This is awesome!  I remember looking into UML a while back because it seemed perfect but the tools I found at the time led me down an endless stream of UML documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Dia?action=show&redirect=Dia), though it's a little old it's free and open source, you can run it on Linux, Mac and Windows.