# Mobile Data Model Diagrams (ERD)

Tags: android, er-diagram

I want to be able to create and edit ERD whenever I want.

**Requirements**

- Platform Android
- Must be simple (e.g. [Quick and Easy Data Model Diagrams (ERD)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/quick-and-easy-data-model-diagrams-erd))

  - Only being able to "draw" the Diagram, don't need the sql export nor others advanced tools.
  - Be able to draw relationship (one to many, many to many, zero or one, etc.).
  - Ne able to draw the "boxes" with the data.

**Optional**

- *Would be great if it was possible to define DataType and create Comments as well.**
- *I would rather that any recommendations were free, but don't mind paying if it fulfils my requirements*
- *Export Diagrams (e.g. to include it in a presentation or other document)*
- *Work offline (this is optional, but has a great value. But not required)*